# how do i make all of the images in my list pop out instead of just the first one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a website for my friends business. I am useing html + css + javascript. There is a section where i am going to have pictures and then next to them a description. But when you click on the picture it blows up in the center and shades out the rest of the screen. So potentially i want to have a list of say 100 pictures and all of them need to be able to blow up in full screen. Im not advanced with javascript but i am trying to learn. If somebody could please help me solve this, i could learn something today.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="css">

  </style>
</head>

<div class="menuscroll">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="myImg" src="chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg" alt="Chena Cannabis" width="300" height="200"></td>
      <td>
        <p style="padding-left:2cm;">this is some text.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="myImg" src="chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg" alt="Chena Cannabis" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="myImg" src="chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg" alt="Chena Cannabis" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="myImg" src="chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg" alt="Chena Cannabis" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="myImg" src="chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg" alt="Chena Cannabis" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="myImg" src="chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg" alt="Chena Cannabis" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>


<script>
</script>

</html>
```

[chenaCan_img/test/1-1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg)

Comment: A fiddle link is helpful in this type of questions.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with a fiddle link. What does it do? and how could I add one?

Comment: ID's in HTML **must** be unique - use classes instead

Comment: For sure, I think actually my problem is in the ID myImg and how that relates to the java script, the thing is I don't really know the most efficient way to repeat that java function I guess.

Comment: @Mamun a fiddle link is ok, but using stack overflows built in snippets is much better...

Comment: @Shadow, that I said thinking of the images.

Comment: oh i see. I added the code snippet. and even with out the images the code behaves correctly for the ID image1.

Comment: I've also posted a picture that i am useing, I'm not sure how to make it run with the stack exchange snippet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove id's from the `img` element and place the `myImg` class. Use `document.getElementsByClassName('myImg')` to get all the elements having `img` class.

`document.getElementsByClassName()` return the array of match nodes. So you have to run a for loop till the `document.getElementsByClassName('myImg').length` to show the popup on every `myImg` click.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
console.log(img.length)
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

function myPopup() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  //alert('hey');
}

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].onclick = myPopup;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menuscroll">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="myImg" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg" alt="Six" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="myImg" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg" alt="Six" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="myImg" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg" alt="Six" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="myImg" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg" alt="Six" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="myImg" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg" alt="Six" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img class="myImg" id="" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VWIy.jpg" alt="Six" width="300" height="200"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bhuwan Bhatt. Thats excellent, I'm still learning javascript, but this is a huge help, I should be able to manipulate it from there. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Happy to help:)